# Checking if a function from the sources of a website is executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

With the "Inspect Element" option in a common browser it is possible to access the "Sources" tab and, not only see the files which the website uses, but also mark a line of code (as shown in the image below at line 463 with a .js file), which will make the browser pause when that line of code is executed (essentially a debugger). In this sense, it seems possible to check if a certain line of code is executed, which is what I need to finish an automation with Python, preferably with Selenium, but which I also don't know how to do.

[image]

Comment: It is not "essentially a debugger", it IS a debugger, and you are setting a breakpoint.  I do not know if it is possible to automate the Chrome debugger with Selenium, but I am dubious.

Comment: Is this .js code part of your own project? If so, I recommend using a JS testing library such as Jest or Mocha to test it, not selenium in python.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium tests are intended to be "black box". That is, you load a page and only access the things that are available in the browser window to verify that behavior is correct. You should NOT try to verify that specific parts of code were written. Even if you can figure out a way to do this, it will make your tests extremely brittle.

If you are writing the JavaScript code, then I suggest using a framework such as Jest or Mocha to test it directly. You still shouldn't verify that a specific line of code is executed, but you can test a function by calling it directly and checking the return value or side effects to make sure they are correct.

Comment: That file is in the sources of a website I do not own, so unfortunately I don't think I can do what you recommended. My purpose is to do a relatively simple bot for a game just for recreation and learning. I have made something similar with Selenium previously, so that's what I'm familiar with.

Comment: @ordptt Yes, if you don't own the JavaScript code, then that is a different thing. What are you trying to accomplish here? Why do you need to check that a specific line of JavaScript code ran?

Comment: @CodeApprentice it is a word game, and it seems that the only way to verify if the answer I insert was correct is to check if the winning condition function was executed, which is not present in the elements tab.

Comment: The only way that I see to verify this without directly checking if the function is executed is to detect if a specific winning audio is played - which I also don't know how to do.

Comment: @ordptt If you play the game manually, how do you know that you won?

Comment: As I said, an specific audio is played and it is the next player turn, which is something that is ran by the .js file.

Comment: @ordptt One option is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536303/detect-audio-with-selenium-webdriver-and-python. Basically you could find a way to detect if your system is playing any sound. This is outside of the features of selenium.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249773/discussion-between-ordptt-and-code-apprentice).